# x86 max/min asm instructions?

Tags: assembly, x86, intrinsics

Are there any asm instructions that can speed up computation of min/max of vector of doubles/integers on Core i7 architecture?

**Update:**

I didn't expect such rich answers, thank you.
So I see that max/min is possible to do without branching.
I have sub-question:

Is there an efficient way to get the index of the biggest double in array?

Comment: What is the host language? If it is c/c++ I wouldn't worry about it too much.

Comment: max of around 300 doubles is in the most inner loop of large program.
85% of time is spent in about 10 out of 8'000 lines of code. Host language doesn't matter just because of that. But yes it is C++

Comment: Related: [What is the instruction that gives branchless FP min and max on x86?](//stackoverflow.com/q/40196817) has more detail about MINSS / MAXSS / MINSD / MAXSD, including their NaN behaviour.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

SSE4 has `PMAXSD` or `PMAXUD` for 32 bit signed/unsigned integers, which might be useful.

SSE2 has `MAXPD` and `MAXSD` which compare between and across pairs of doubles, so you follow n/2-1 MAXPDs with one MAXSD to get the max of a vector of n, with the usual interlacing of loads and operations.

There are MIN equivalents of the above.

For the double case, you're probably not going to do better in assembler than a half-decent C++ compiler in SSE mode:

```
peregrino:$ g++ -O3 src/min_max.cpp -o bin/min_max
peregrino:$ g++ -O3 -msse4 -mfpmath=sse src/min_max.cpp -o bin/min_max_sse
peregrino:$ time bin/min_max
0,40

real    0m0.874s
user    0m0.796s
sys 0m0.004s
peregrino:$ time bin/min_max_sse 
0,40

real    0m0.457s
user    0m0.404s
sys 0m0.000s
```

where min_max computes min and max of an array of 500 doubles 100,000 times using a naive loop:

```
bool min_max ( double array[], size_t len, double& min, double& max )
{
    double min_value = array [ 0 ];
    double max_value = array [ 0 ];

    for ( size_t index = 1; index < len; ++index ) {
        if ( array [ index ] < min_value ) min_value = array [ index ];
        if ( array [ index ] > max_value ) max_value = array [ index ];
    }

    min = min_value;
    max = max_value;
}
```

---

In response to part two, the traditional optimisation to remove branching from a max operation is to compare the values, get the flag as a single bit ( giving 0 or 1 ), subtract one ( giving 0 or 0xffff_ffff) and 'and' it with the xor of the two possible results, so you get the equivalent of `( a > best ?  ( current_index ^ best_index ) : 0 )  ^ best_index )`. I doubt there's a simple SSE way of doing that, simply because SSE tends to operate on packed values rather than tagged values; there are some horizontal index operations, so you could try finding the max, then subtracting that from all elements in the original vector, then gather the sign bit, and the zero signed one would correspond to the index of the max, but that would probably not be an improvement unless you were using shorts or bytes.

Comment: You only need log2(vector_length) shuffle + MAXPS/MAXPD operations, not VL/2, to get the horizontal max of a single SIMD vector.  It's basically the same idea as [a horizontal sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996764/fastest-way-to-do-horizontal-float-vector-sum-on-x86): narrow in half every time.  (Or to leave the result broadcast to every element, swap high/low).

Comment: Unrolling with multiple accumulators should give a better than 2x speedup, if you're not bottlenecked on memory.  (`MAXPD` has 3 or 4 cycle latency, but a throughput of 1 per cycle, so you need the compiler to emit asm that uses multiple vectors and combines them at the end of the array.)  clang tends to do this while auto-vectorizing, but gcc still usually doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

MAXPS and MINPS from SSE both operate on packed single-precision floating point numbers. PMAXSW, PMINSW, PMAXUB and PMINUB all operate on packed 8-bit words, either signed or unsigned.  Please note that these compare the two input SSE registers or  address locations element-wise and store the result into an SSE register or memory location.

The SSE2 versions of MAXPS and MINPS should work on double-precision floats.

What compiler and optimization flags are you using?  gcc 4.0 and better should automatically vectorize operations if your target supports them, earlier versions may need a specific flag.

Answer (score 2):

if your are using Intel's [IPP](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-ipp/) library you can use the vector [statistical functions](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/ipp/ipps/ipps_ch5/ch5_statistical_functions.html#ch5_statistical_functions)  to calculate vector  min/max (among other things)

Answer (score 2):

In response to your second question: on most platforms, there are libraries that already contained optimized implementations of this very operation (and most other simple vector operations).  **Use them**.

- On OS X, there is `vDSP_maxviD( )` and `cblas_idamax( )` in the Accelerate.framework
- The Intel compilers include the IPP and MKL libraries, which have high performance implementations, including `cblas_idamax( )`
- Most Linux systems will have `cblas_idamax( )` in the BLAS library, which may or may not be well-tuned depending on its provenance; users who care about performance will generally have a good implementation (or can be persuaded to install one)
- If all else fails, you can use ATLAS (Automatically Tuned Linear Algebra Software) to get a decent performance implementation on the target platform

Answer (score 1):

Update: I just realized you said "array", not "vector" in part 2.  I'll leave this here anyway in case it's useful.

---

re: part two: find the index of the max/min element in an SSE vector:

- Do a horizontal maximum.  For a 128b vector of 2 `double` elements, that's just one `shufpd` + `maxpd` to leave the result broadcast to both elements.

  For other cases, it will of course take more steps.  See [Fastest way to do horizontal float vector sum on x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996764/fastest-way-to-do-horizontal-float-vector-sum-on-x86) for ideas, replacing `addps` with `maxps` or `minps`.  (But note that 16-bit integer is special, because you can use SSE4 `phminposuw`.  For max, subtract from 255)
- Do a packed-compare between the vector original vector and the vector where every element is the max.

  (`pcmpeqq` integer bit patterns or the usual `cmpeqpd` would both work for the `double` case).
- [`int _mm_movemask_pd (__m128d a)` (`movmskpd`)](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=5452,4067,4729,94,76,270,3622,3874,3984,2679,1902,1234,3603,3517,3593&text=movmskpd) to get the compare result as an integer bitmap.
- bit-scan (`bsf`) it for the (first) match: [`index = _bit_scan_forward(cmpmask)`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=5452,4067,4729,94,76,270,3622,3874,3984,2679,1902,1234,3603,3517,3593,376,374&text=bsf).  cmpmask = 0 is impossible if you used integer compares (because at least one element will match even if they are NaN).

This should compile to only 6 instructions (including a `movapd`).  Yup, just checked on [the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:'%23include+%3Cimmintrin.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cx86intrin.h%3E%0A%0Aint+maxpos(__m128d+v)+%7B%0A++__m128d+swapped+%3D+_mm_shuffle_pd(v,v,+1)%3B%0A++__m128d+maxbcast+%3D+_mm_max_pd(swapped,+v)%3B%0A++__m128d+cmp+%3D+_mm_cmpeq_pd(maxbcast,+v)%3B%0A++int+cmpmask+%3D+_mm_movemask_pd(cmp)%3B%0A++return+_bit_scan_forward(cmpmask)%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:37.03346314087034,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g63,filters:(___0:(),b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0',jquery:'3.2.1',length:1,prevObject:(___0:(sizzle1502091479452:(undefined:(legend:!(5,0,'1')))),length:1,prevObject:(___0:(jQuery321054684297701271231:(display:''),sizzle1502091479452:(undefined:(legend:!(5,0,'1')))),length:1))),options:'-Wall++-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B14+-O3+-fverbose-asm+-march%3Dnehalem',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+6.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)',t:'0')),k:31.663970438121716,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang400,filters:(___0:(),b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0',jquery:'3.2.1',length:1,prevObject:(___0:(sizzle1502091479452:(undefined:(legend:!(10,0,'1')))),length:1,prevObject:(___0:(jQuery321054684297701271231:(display:''),sizzle1502091479452:(undefined:(legend:!(10,0,'1')))),length:1))),options:'-stdlib%3Dlibc%2B%2B+-Wall+-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B14+-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+4.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)',t:'0')),k:31.30256642100796,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',m:69.39890710382514,n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+6.3',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:30.601092896174865,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) and it does, with SSE.

```
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <x86intrin.h>

int maxpos(__m128d v) {
  __m128d swapped = _mm_shuffle_pd(v,v, 1);
  __m128d maxbcast = _mm_max_pd(swapped, v);
  __m128d cmp = _mm_cmpeq_pd(maxbcast, v);
  int cmpmask = _mm_movemask_pd(cmp);
  return _bit_scan_forward(cmpmask);
}
```

Note that [`_mm_max_pd` is not commutative with NaN inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40196817/what-is-the-instruction-that-gives-branchless-fp-min-and-max-on-x86/40199125#40199125).  If NaN is possible, and you don't care about performance on Intel Nehalem, you might consider using `_mm_cmpeq_epi64` to compare bit-patterns.  Bypass-delay from float to vec-int is a problem on Nehalem, though.

NaN != NaN in IEEE floating point, so the `_mm_cmpeq_pd` result mask could be all-zero in the all-NaN case.

Another thing you can do in the 2-element case to always get a 0 or 1 is to replace the bit-scan with `cmpmask >> 1`.  (`bsf` is weird with input = all-zero).

Answer (score -1):

In response to your second question, it may be worthwhile to you to think about the way you collect and store this data.

You may store the data in a B-tree that keeps the data sorted at all times, requiring only logarithmic compare operations.

Then you know at all times where the maximum is.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_tree

Comment: Since you are dealing with only 300 doubles, a self-balanced binary tree is probably best.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree