# Finding max and min in assembly

Tags: loops, assembly

trying to do the following in asembly:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
main(){
        int a,b,c=0,d=0;
        for(a = -3; a >= 3; a++){
                b = a*a*a*a*a*a*a - a*a*a*a*4 - a*a*a + a*a*7 + 30*a;
                if(b>=c){
                        c=b;
                }
                if(b<=d){
                        d=b;
                }
        }
    printf("The max value is" + c + "\n");
    printf("The min value is" + d + "\n");
}
```

I've don't code in assembly much and I want to be able to understand my code when I look at the assembly languages, so simply converting this into assembly with gcc is kinda out of the question.

My goal here is to use as little `nop` as possible when I make this code. So I suppose my questions would be:

1. What is the best way to do powers in assembly without a massive
   amount of re-entering things into the register? Is that even
   possible?
2. When I loop in assembly, will I want `a`'s value set already? or can
   I program it kind of like this for loop here? (can I avoid while-looping to save space)

Comment: @Christian: You're correct, but read the prose. The question is asking how something equivalent would be done in assembly, using C as an model of what they want to happen.

Comment: @Christian: Even if it is homework, they are asking a valid question and are not asking for the work to be done for them.

Comment: Ok. Given. But I can see nothing he tried so far.

Comment: Two suggestions: 1) Excellent link on GCC/x86 assembly: [Programming from the Ground Up, Jonathan Bartlett](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/pgubook/), 2) "gcc -S" your C snippets and analyze the results.  "converting this into assembly with gcc" is emphatically *NOT* "kinda outy of the question".  It's *RECOMMENDED*.  IMHO...

Comment: Not sure what you're exactly asking, for 1) Are you looking for avoid transfer data by using registers?

Comment: @Ryan, I found this interesting [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969809/x86-max-min-asm-instructions/1969860#1969860) you might wanna check.

Comment: @ChristianMark I was given parameters to write a program and I knew how to write it in C, but not in assembly. The code you see is my own and not verbatim from an assignment, merely my understanding of how I am to do the assignment with proper computer logic in another language I understand. Also thank you for the link, but I fear it's a bit too confusing for my current understanding of assembly.

Comment: @Jack I think what I was asking was if I could simply do something along the lines of: do simply just multiply over and over again or is there a function/method for using exponents?

Comment: I got now. Well, usually assemblies doesn't have such features(as far I know) and then you need to write yourself. But the only way to know it is by reading the documentation.

Comment: @Jack I think I may very well just use a loop to do it, kind of like having a loop that has an input value that lets you run the loop the same many times as the given value.

Comment: `for (a = -3; a >= 3; a++)` -- how often do you think this loop will execute?

Comment: @KerrekSB I imagine it should execute about 7 times.

Comment: Instead of using "a*a*a*a*a*a*a - a*a*a*a*..." you should use "a*a*a*a*(a*a*a-...)" to save time and space. Unfortunately there is no possibility to do powers in assembly language more efficiently. However some CPUs (x86 not - as far as I know) already provide a "min" and a "max" instruction or conditional "mov" instructions ("isel" on some PowerPCs) that may be used to optimize the "min" and "max" operations.

Answer (score 0):

This code is a tremendous example of what compiler optimization can do. Assuming you meant `for (a = -3; a <= 3; a++) ...` then you can re-code this into:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define val(a)  (a*a*a*a*a*a*a - a*a*a*a*4 - a*a*a + a*a*7 + 30*a)

#define MIN(X, Y)       ((X) > (Y) ? (Y) : (X))
#define MAX(X, Y)       ((X) > (Y) ? (X) : (Y))

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int c = 0, d = 0, a;

    for (a = -3; a <= 3; a++)
            c = MAX(val(a), c), d = MIN(val(a), d);
    printf("max value is %d,\nmin value is %d\n", c, d);
    return 0;
}
```

Intel's ICC turns this directly into:

```
  4006f9:       [ ... meaningless "ICC glue" instruction ... ]
  4006fd:       bf 7c 0b 40 00          mov    $0x400b7c,%edi
  400702:       be c5 07 00 00          mov    $0x7c5,%esi
  400707:       [ ... meaningless "ICC glue" instruction ... ]
  40070e:       ba 31 f6 ff ff          mov    $0xfffff631,%edx
  400713:       33 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  400715:       [ ... meaningless "ICC glue" instruction ... ]
  400719:       e8 2a fe ff ff          callq  400548 <printf@plt>
  40071e:       33 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  400720:       48 89 ec                mov    %rbp,%rsp
  400723:       5d                      pop    %rbp
  400724:       c3                      retq
```

CLang (3.3) also can to it, it creates:

```
0000000000400b60 <main>:
  400b60:       50                      push   %rax
  400b61:       bf 6c 0c 40 00          mov    $0x400c6c,%edi
  400b66:       be c5 07 00 00          mov    $0x7c5,%esi
  400b6b:       ba 31 f6 ff ff          mov    $0xfffff631,%edx
  400b70:       30 c0                   xor    %al,%al
  400b72:       e8 39 fd ff ff          callq  4008b0 <printf@plt>
  400b77:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  400b79:       5a                      pop    %rdx
  400b7a:       c3                      retq
```

GCC (up to and including 4.8.1) doesn't seem able to compile-time calculate in this case, while it unrolls the loop it inserts a sequence of multiplies, conditional moves / SSE min/max instructions.

But if you explicitly unroll the loop in code, manually, then you get:

```
c = MAX(val(-3), 0); d = MIN(val(-3), 0);
c = MAX(val(-2), c); d = MIN(val(-2), d);
c = MAX(val(-1), c); d = MIN(val(-1), d);
c = MAX(val(0), c); d = MIN(val(0), d);
c = MAX(val(1), c); d = MIN(val(1), d);
c = MAX(val(2), c); d = MIN(val(2), d);
c = MAX(val(3), c); d = MIN(val(3), d);
```

and GCC is able to calculate it at compile-time:

```
0000000000400630 <main>:
  400630:       48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  400634:       ba 31 f6 ff ff          mov    $0xfffff631,%edx
  400639:       be c5 07 00 00          mov    $0x7c5,%esi
  40063e:       bf 50 07 40 00          mov    $0x400750,%edi
  400643:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  400645:       e8 79 fe ff ff          callq  4004c0 <printf@plt>
  40064a:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  40064c:       48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  400650:       c3                      retq
```

Morale: The best result in this case you get by *not* trying to optimize the assembler output :)

Comment: I should've added, just to make it clear, that this specific sourcecode has an _analytically computable_ result, i.e. you can figure out the values for `c` / `d` at the end using "pencil & paper". That's what the compilers do here. Whether this misses the point of the assignment or not, it's the _best result_ for this case. If you wish to see how the compiler expresses the min/max (on x86, three options: "classical" `cmp` and `j...`, `cmp` and conditional moves, and SSE min/max instructions), crank the range boundaries up.